# What size power supply do I need to connect two 5 meter LED strips?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

I want to buy 2 of these [5 meter LED strips](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1-20M-RGB-5050-SMD-waterproof-300-LED-Light-Strip-Flexible-IR-Remote-12V-power-/161255347539?pt=US_String_Lights_Fairy_Lights&var=&hash=item258b915553) to make a 10 meter run.

What power supply do I need to have to avoid voltage drop? what controller do I need? How do I connect those 2 LED strips?

Comment: That page lists exactly what you need to get. Just scroll down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says 2.1 amps/5 meters for the 30 LED/meter strip, 4.2 amps/5 meters for the 60 LED/meter strip. So, that's either a 5 amp @ 12V supply or a 10 amp @ 12V supply.

I would not recommend hooking up the two strips in serial; the LEDs at the end of the second strip will likely be much dimmer than the ones at the beginning. You can get around this by running a thicker cable in parallel with the strip.